# Apache HTTP Client - 401 error with Malformed challenge: Out of sequence NTLM response message warning

Tags: java, apache, apache-httpclient-4.x

We are facing a problem within our application where in when two HTTP requests are made using the HTTP client concurrently, at times, one of them is returning a 401 even when valid NTLM authentication is passed.

Following is an extract from our logs

```
2019-09-07 16:12:27.620  INFO [nio-8087-exec-9] i.c.d.c.f.s.services.SharePointService   : Executing request: http://xxxxxx/sites/utp/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('/sites/utp/Shared%20Documents/InstanceDocuments/41931/Input/uTW0DIz5dR') with headers: [Accept: application/json; odata=verbose, Content-Type: application/json; odata=verbose, X-RequestDigest: 0xA03754C393422E3EEFB176F804EAF942411EB26E7DF7270C8B4421203671D101077D103C54303961FEE57F5878A3248D53909B39CDD9EC6AB30D38A6FCBB8255,07 Sep 2019 10:28:34 -0000]
2019-09-07 16:12:27.621  INFO [nio-8087-exec-3] i.c.d.c.f.s.services.SharePointService   : Executing request: http://xxxxxx/sites/utp/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('/sites/utp/Shared%20Documents/InstanceDocuments/41931/Output/euigNyrkQ8')/Files with headers: [Accept: application/json; odata=verbose, Content-Type: application/json; odata=verbose, X-RequestDigest: 0xA03754C393422E3EEFB176F804EAF942411EB26E7DF7270C8B4421203671D101077D103C54303961FEE57F5878A3248D53909B39CDD9EC6AB30D38A6FCBB8255,07 Sep 2019 10:28:34 -0000]
2019-09-07 16:12:27.638  WARN [nio-8087-exec-3] o.a.http.impl.auth.HttpAuthenticator     : Malformed challenge: Out of sequence NTLM response message
2019-09-07 16:12:27.638  INFO [nio-8087-exec-9] i.c.d.c.f.s.services.SharePointService   : Got response from URI: http://xxxxxx/sites/utp/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('/sites/utp/Shared%20Documents/InstanceDocuments/41931/Input/uTW0DIz5dR') with status: 404
2019-09-07 16:12:27.639  INFO [nio-8087-exec-3] i.c.d.c.f.s.services.SharePointService   : Got response from URI: http://xxxxxx/sites/utp/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('/sites/utp/Shared%20Documents/InstanceDocuments/41931/Output/euigNyrkQ8')/Files with status: 401
```

As shown in the logs above, the first request is sent by thread 9 and the second is sent by thread 3 just 1 millisecond later. We are receiving a warning in thread 3 and then subsequently response from thread 9 is printed and then the error 401 is returned.

The warning says

> Malformed challenge: Out of sequence NTLM response message

Please note that 404 is a valid response for our application.

At the moment, we are not sure if this is a problem with concurrency within the apache httpclient library or it has something to do with the server side configuration.

Apache HTTP Client Version: 4.5.5
Target server is SharePoint 2013

Comment: Your code is not using the same `HttpContext` instances concurrently while executing requests from different threads, is it?

Comment: We are creating only one instance of HttpClientContext and passing it along with each http.execute method call..

Comment: Incorrect use of `HttpContext` is the most common cause of "Out of sequence NTLM response message" problem.

Comment: Is HttpClientContext a subtype of HttpContext?

Comment: Yes, it is.....